# how do add event listener to Jquery Event , which is created using Jquery Event constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a small custom event. I am very new to jquery and JS in general , have a look at my code below:

```
$(function () {

    test = $.Event('click');

    $('a').on( test , function(e){
        console.log(e.target);
        return false;
    })

});
```

now in the above code when the a is clicked the `test` event is never fired , the reason being the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation clearly states that the 1st parameter must be a string .

Now my question is suppose I use the `event constructor` as discussed in [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) Jquery documentation. How do I attach an event then to `test`?

Comment: From a curiosity point of view, if you know the event is going to be click, why dont you just feed click into the jQuery?   `$("a").on("click", function(){});`

Comment: @Fallenreaper , i can't :( i am trying to create a functinality with custom events only !

Comment: ahh, making a new custom Event Object and feeding this new event into jQuery for manipulation.  So in theory, you would have an event called: "Foo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.type` to get the event type from event object. however you can not pass the entire event object in on method as it expects event name and not the event itself:

```
$('a').on(test.type, function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    return false;
})
```

Comment: yes , but i need to use a custom event ! .. not a normal Jquery event , i am trying to create a demo where in i want to test if preventDefault() and DefaultPrevented() work with custom events , and thats why , your solution is a no-go for me !

Comment: You can not pass the event handler to on method. You can get the type from event however if required.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript solution:

```
function Dispatcher(){
    "use strict";

    this.listeners = [];

    /* public function dispatch
     * @Description: Execute the callback subscribed to an event.
     * @Arguments: eventName
     * @Return: void;
     */
    this.trigger = function (eventName, eventData) {
        if(this.listeners[eventName]) {
            for(var i=0; i < this.listeners[eventName].length; i++) {
                this.listeners[eventName][i].callback(eventData);
                if(this.listeners[eventName][i].executeOnce) {
                    this.listeners[eventName].splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /* public function on()
     * @Description: Subscribe  the callback to certain event
     * @Arguments: eventName, callback, executeOnce.
     * @Return void;
     */
    this.on = function(eventName, callback, executeOnce) {

        var listener = {
                callback: callback,
                executeOnce: executeOnce
        };

        if(!this.listeners[eventName]) { this.listeners[eventName] = []; }
        this.listeners[eventName].push(listener);
    };

    /* public function off()
     * @Description: Un-subscribe all the callbacks subscribed to certain event.
     * @Arguments: eventName
     * @Return void;
     */
    this.off = function(eventName) {
        if(this.listeners[eventName]) {
            delete this.listeners[eventName];
        }
    };

    /* public function one()
     * @Description: Subscribe the callback to be executed only once to the eventName
     * @Arguments: eventName, callback
     * @Return void;
     */
    this.one = function(eventName, callback) {
        this.on(eventName, callback, true);
    };
}

var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.one('customEvent', function(eventData) {
   console.log('customEventFired');
});
dispatcher.one('customEvent', function(eventData) {
   console.log('another action that depends on this event');
});
dispatcher.trigger('customEvent');
dispatcher.trigger('customEvent');
```

Comment: This is what i don't want , but thanks for trying haha , not going pure JS any sooner LOL

Comment: No problem, Know that the OP is about jquery, but posted this to add a different way to do it without depending on a library. its just another example :)

Answer (score 1):

Custom events are convenient to use for [event triggering](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and especially for artificial (non-DOM) events (although you can use any name).

For example:

```js
var test = $.Event('test');
test.customProperty = 'Something';

var hostObject = {
    name: 'root'
};

$(hostObject).on('test', function(e) {
    alert(e.customProperty);
})

$(hostObject).trigger(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```